# Is it it possible to fill an Apache log file by sending lots of invalid file (404) requests?

Tags: apache

If yes, how big can my error_log file can get?

And after that, Apache will remove the oldest log from the file or will Apache stop logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a maximum file size in any file system, after reaching that size apache can't append to it. but making that much request can take decades (100-150 bytes will appended on each file not found error)